# How to insert a time range in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

So I have a field,

```
,Time_ TIME NULL
```

And this field is meant to represent the time a lecture would take place. In this case, the lecture would take place between 1:00 and 2:00. Is it possible to insert this time range or would I only be able to insert a starting time? i.e.

```
,'1:00PM'
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Use two fields, such as `startTime` and `endTime`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it possible to insert a time range into a single field? Yes.
Is it possible to insert a time range into a field formatted as TIME? No.
Is it a good idea to store two data points in one field? Absolutely not.
Am I going to suggest any ways that you COULD store both in one field? Sorry, but no, I'm afraid I'm not.

You'll run into problems parsing the field. You'll run into problems calculating the length of a lecture. You'll just run into problems every time you turn around.

I imagine you want to display the something like "Math 101, 11:00-12:00", and that's fine. In your presentation layer, be it an SSRS report, a spreadsheet, a web page, what have you, call for the class name, the start time, and the end time, then format them appropriately at the output stage. It keeps your data manageable for the next use case.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot insert a time range.  If you need to know the range of the lecture you could create columns for 'lecture_starttime' and 'lecture_endtime'.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend storing both times and calculating the length:

```
start_time
end_time
```

This will cater for lectures that aren't always 1 hour long. You can calculate the length as end_time - start_time.